# Unknown custom element error in Vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, sass, webstorm

I started creating a project in vue.js based on this one:
https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vuetify-material-dashboard

When trying to integrate `TableList.vue` component, I get an error:

`Unknown custom element: <material-card> - did you register the component correctly?`

Vue.js project was created using webstorm. I copied over `styles` folder and enabled watcher to compile scss files into css. I run project using `npm serve` command in WebStorm.

My App.vue looks a little different like this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <TheBar />
    <TheNavigationDrawer />
    <TheView />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

import TheBar from '@/components/core/TheBar.vue'
import TheNavigationDrawer from "@/components/core/TheNavigationDrawer";
import TheView from '@/components/core/TheView.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    TheBar,
    TheNavigationDrawer,
    TheView
  },
  data: () => ({
  }),
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import './styles/index.scss';
</style>
```

As you can see I am importing the full file, which in turn imports `_cards.scss` file which should have definition of material-card component. Is this how it works?

I tried registering component manually by adding material-card to `components` property but it fails to parse kebab-case properly because of '-' sign.

What also intrigues me is that the original creator NEVER registers material-card component so how the hell does his TableList.vue component know it?

I also found this guide - https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9. However I don't see a webpack.config.js file anywhere, where is this?

Any help is greatly appreciated. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of importing components into your Vue instance. For the case of the project you're working from, the vuetify library is imported at the root instance which allows all components to be available globally. This means you don't need to import the desired components within specific .vue files.

It's likely that you haven't installed all of the dependencies correctly. Or you have not properly imported these dependencies within main.js. Check that these dependecies (found in package.json) have been installed by running *npm list*.